# how to increment image filename firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to increment image filename when new image is uploaded but it doesn't work
here is the code:

```
public int getImageCount(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int count = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot
                .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_posts))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .getChildren()) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void uploadNewPost(final String caption, int count, String imgUrl, Bitmap bm) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPost: Attempting to upload new post");

        FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();

        String user_id = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();

        StorageReference storageReference = mStorageReference
                .child(filePaths.FIREBASE_IMAGE_STORAGE + "/" + user_id + "/photo" + (count++));
```

Comment: use count++ it will increment each time.

Comment: can you type all of it because it doesn't work :P My app crashes